# Internet stops working after connecting an ethernet cable

Tags: router, internet, ethernet

Good morning/evening. 
So I have a laptop at home, and like most people I use the internet. A couple of months ago I bought an ethernet cable for a much more reliable connection for online games, however just two weeks ago I started experiencing a problem I cannot comprehend.

Whenever the ethernet cable is connected to the router, the internet just goes away. The green light that indicates that there's an internet connection turns off, however, the wifi signal still works and I can still connect to the network.

I have to restart the router to get the internet to work again, and after that, throughout the day the internet goes off at random instances. After that, things return to normal.

I can connect to the internet via wifi and it works fine.

Is there a solution to this or should I proceed to contact customer support?

Comment: Is it a problem of your ISP or that Ethernet cable?

Comment: That I have not figured out. Is it possible that the ethernet cable itself could cause this? I will purchase another one to see for myself.
As for the ISP, they provided the router, if the ethernet isn't the problem, they're the people I should ultimately talk to.

Comment: Check that Ethernet cable with a LED and a battery if there any short circuit in it. Also try to ping, nslookup, traceroute command in PC to solve routing issue.

Comment: When you say the "internet just goes away". Do you mean only for your laptop? Do you have other devices connected via wired ethernet? Where is the green light coming from? Your laptop? When you connect the ethernet, your laptop should get an IP. Finding out the IP, along with DNS IP should help you a lot in troubleshooting.

Comment: How is the IP address of your PC set when it uses the Ethernet port? DHCP or fixed address? And if fixed, would it clash with the IP of the router?

Answer (score 1):

There are some steps you may do,
1. Troubleshooter- When internet is gone,right click on the icon which indicates internet connection and click on **troubleshoot problems**. And then follow the instructions(Usually next ,next and so on).

2.If the problem persists then you may try to reset your router, if you don't know how then please contact to customer care.